# Ruby on Rails 4.0.4: How do I set up the Environment Variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I set up the environment variables?
I already tried it as you can see.
***Code-Snippet:***

**app/local_env.yml:**

```
MAIL_DOMAIN: 'gmail.com'
MAIL_USERNAME: "username@googlemail.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD: "password"
```

**app/config/application.rb:**

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

**output (RailsConsole):**

```
>> ENV['MAIL_USERNAME']
nil

>> ENV['MAIL_DOMAIN']
nil
```

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Is local_env.yml saved in the root of the Rails app, or in the config folder?

Comment: It's saved in the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to load your file from the `config` folder using `File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')`, but you saved the file in the root of your app.

Your `YAML.load` block only executes if the file exists; since it can't find `config/local_env.yml`, it doesn't load anything.

You should move `local_env.yml` to your `config` folder. If you'd rather keep the file in the root of your app, then change the line to:

```
env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'local_env.yml')
```

Comment: Seems legit. Is there any convention? Should I saved it in the config-folder? Mhh.. The env_var dont configurate something, i guess. There are only saved in the local_env.yml, because of the gitignore.
Well there is allready a database.yml, so that I move the local_env.yml to the config-folder.
Thank you very much.